# Selecting rows same value in colA but different values in colB w/ condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in SQL Server that has a structure like this:

```
id     m_id    r_id
-------------------
1      1       1
2      2       2
3      2       2
4      3       2
5      3       5
6      4       5
7      5       3
```

I need to figure out how I can get the m_id's of records where the r_id are different but only have the values of 2 OR 5.

So query would result in these rows

```
m_id    r_id
-------------
3       2
3       5
```

Even better if I could just get the m_ids where that condition is bet so that I can update those records

```
m_id
----
3
```

On a side note, are there any good resources like a book or a website I can read so that I get a good fundamental grasp of DB querying?

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT m_id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY m_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 2
    AND MIN(r_id) = 2
    AND MAX(r_id) = 5
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ecdc65e18fb50434df401ce1f6e7114)** with your sample data returns:

```
| m_id |
| ---: |
|    3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have duplicates.  I think I would go for:

```
select m_id
from t
group by m_id
having sum(case when r_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when r_id = 5 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when r_id not in (2, 5) then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

You can also do this without the condition aggregation constructs:

```
select m_id
from t
group by m_id
having min(r_id) = 2 and
       max(r_id) = 5 and
       count(distinct r_id) = 2;
```

However, this does not generalize as easily to other values.

Actually, for generalization, you might like this:

```
with r as (
      select *
      from (values (2), (5)) v(r_id)
     )
select m_id
from t left join
     r
     on t.r_id = r.r_id
group by m_id
having count(*) = count(r.r_id) and  -- all ids match
       count(distinct t.r_id) = (select count(*) from r);
```

Comment: Your third one is giving me the correct results plus `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`.

Comment: @avery_larry . . . You don't need to worry about the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I think I like the other answers are probably better; but just in case, here's an example using exists:

```
declare @table table (m_id int, r_id int)
insert into @table
values (1,2),(2,2),(2,2),(3,2),(3,5),(4,5),(5,3),(4,2),(4,4)

select distinct m_id
from @table t
where exists (select m_id from @table where r_id = 2 and m_id = t.m_id)
   and exists (select m_id from @table where r_id = 5 and m_id = t.m_id)
   and not exists (select m_id from @table where r_id not in (2, 5) and m_id = t.m_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select the distinct m_id that meet your conditions:

To do this on sql, you would do (is not got it written as !-=):

```
Select DISTINCT(m_id)
FROM TableName
Where m_id != r_id    
and (m_id = 2 or m_id =5)
```

Where you take all the m_id that are different from the r_id, and the r_id are only the ones different from 3 or different from 5. From this subgroup you select distinct m_id to get you to your result of "3". Distinct takes away duplications in the previous result, that would be duplications in the 'Select'.

Comment: I had (m_id = 3 or m_id =5) instead of (m_id =2 or m_id = 5). A silly typo. It's fine now

Comment: Nope, no it is not fine now.